# Changing web.config from command line

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I have an ASP.NET application running under IIS.  I'd like to be able to change one of the web.config values in Application Settings.  I know it's possible to change it programmatically as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260317/change-a-web-config-programmatically-with-c-net/2260335#2260335) but I'm wondering if the same thing can be accomplished from the command line.

The IIS 7 Manager allows application settings and connection strings (among other options) to be changed.  My hope is there is a way to do the same via the command line for IIS 6 and/or 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use powershell to modify the web.config.

Answer (score 6):

You can use AppCmd.exe which is included with IIS 7.0 and above, in fact Configuration Editor in IIS Manager will automatically generate the command line for you, for example here it will set the test key to NewValue for the /TestApp inside Default Web Site:

```
appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site/TestApp" -section:appSettings /[key='test'].value:"NewValue"
```

Comment: Is there anything like that for IIS 6, too?

Comment: To modify the web.config files there is no built-in command line , however to modify the IIS configuration there are adminscripts inside \inetpub\ that will allow you to set the IIS configuration through command line.