# Editing function for an XML Gridview in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, xml, visual-studio-2010

I want to write, update or edit a function for an XML gridview in ASP.net (in visual studio 2010), but I don't know which action I should use?

This is my code but it doesn't work. When I click edit on the gridview an exception occured:

```
 private DataSet ds;
    DataRow r;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("../web.config"));
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["user"];
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.RowIndex;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {

        r = ds.Tables["user"].Rows[e.AffectedRows];
        r["password"] = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].ToString(), "MD5");


        ds.AcceptChanges();
        ds.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("web.config"));
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I may have got this wrong but are you trying to amend the web.config file by loading into a gridview? I don't think you can do things like that with web.config - so it's probably to be expected that it's throwing erorrs.

For amending the web.config at runtime have you considered using [WebConfigurationManager](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=102). The object is built with this in mind. Although the previous link says ASP.Net 2.0 and 3.5 it would be fine in 4.0 (Visual Studio 2010). This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260317/change-a-web-config-programmatically-with-c-sharp-net) gives a very clear code sample.