# Make edit XML cause server to restart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Any edits in `web.config` file cause IIS to restart the site, am I right?
So I need to setup my custom XML in such way that edits in it also cause the site to be restarted. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.

1. Have your custom xml in the web.config, using your own [Custom Configuration Section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) and then modify the web.config like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260317/change-a-web-config-programmatically-with-c-sharp-net) for example,
2. Save your changes to your own XML and call [HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/SV-SE/library/system.web.httpruntime.unloadappdomain.aspx).
3. Or save your changes to your own XML and do something like:

   var webConfig = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\Web.config";
   IO.File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc(webConfig, DateTime.UtcNow);