# Share DB-connection through service in .NET?

Tags: .net, sqlconnection

beginners question: suppose I have a server on which multiple .NET services are running, but they would all use the same (configurable) sql-db connection parameters. What would be the best way to let the end user configure the connection parameters and share these with all the services?

Thanks!

Edit: the purpose is to provide a gui so after installation of the services, the system admin can easily set op the connection which should then be accesses by these services.

Comment: Why should an end user be able to configure machine wide configurations?
Isn't this a task which should be accomplished by an administrator, who has a dedicated backend for this?

Comment: Sorry, wrong choice of words. By end-user I mean the system administrator. Ofcourse, this administrator would have to log in, but the purpose is to provide a gui to set up the db connection for multiple services. My question is thus how I can share this connection details.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [Change a web.config programmatically with C# (.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260317/change-a-web-config-programmatically-with-c-sharp-net)

Since you'd have access to every service from your backend you could iterate through every connection string with something along those lines:

```
foreach(var service in servicelist)
{
  var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
  var section = (ConnectionStringsSection)configuration.GetSection("connectionStrings");
  section.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString = "Data Source=...";
  configuration.Save();
}
```