# Single Website Directory / Multiple IIS Websites (Multiple web.config files)

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have inherited some very old asp code. I need to resolve a design problem because of it, described below.

> I have 3 customers... Foo, Bar and Baz.

I have a folder called...

> c:\WebSites\Site.v15.07

I have 3 websites in IIS defined as...

> Website.Foo
>
> Website.Bar
>
> Website.Baz

They all point to the 15.07 directory.

There are 3 other folders called...

> c:\WebConfigurations\Foo
>
> c:\WebConfigurations\Bar
>
> c:\WebConfigurations\Baz

... which all contain client specific files for each of the 3 sites. Uploaded images etc.

Each of the 3 customers has their own database that the website sits on.

I need to set (ideally, using a web.config) the connection string for each of the 3 sites.

If I put this in the web.config in the root of the website directory, they will all share the same setting.

Is there a way of adding the settings/web.config in IIS at the "website" level so that each site can be set differently?

Comment: You can try using this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45889661/several-asp-net-sites-that-are-sharing-application-files-but-using-different-th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put only the common configuration in `Web.config` in the application folder.

When the application is first loading, programmatically load the client-specific config file from the respective folder and programmatically merge the info into the configuration info in memory.

Example of programmatically editing configuration info in memory:

[Change a web.config programmatically with C# (.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260317/change-a-web-config-programmatically-with-c-sharp-net)

```
var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
var section = (ConnectionStringsSection)configuration.GetSection("connectionStrings");
section.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString = "Data Source=...";
```

In your case you'll want to make two calls to `WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration`, one to open the application config and once to load the client configuration. Then copy data from client config to the in-memory application config (don't call `Save()` per the referenced question--that's a different use case).

Comment: I have tried this but it seems that without calling save(), using ConfigurationManager doesn't use the settings in memory. Is this correct?

Comment: @Beakie, `Save()` will persist the changes to disk. You don't need to call it if you only want to affect the settings in memory. In my own usage I adjust setting sin memory from an outside source when needed but have never persisted the changes to disk.

Comment: But the moment I dispose of the WebConfigurationManager variable, the settings are forgotten. Also ConfigurationManager doesn't reflect the changes made via WebConfigurationManager. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: @Beakie, I'm not following what you're saying. `WebConfigurationManager` is used statically, so it's never disposed. I would expect that opening the configuration from both `WebConfigurationManager` and `ConfigurationManager` independently will load two separate copies of the config into memory. Changes to one will not be reflected in the other.