# Editing web.config in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I want to edit a web.config to add some sections programatically.
For example  and `<configSections>`. How can I go about achieving this in C#? My application is ASP.Net website.

I know that I can do `WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.identityModel")` to get an instance of the identity section, but cant see any way of actually editing/adding it?

Comment: Did you look at this one https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d68a872e-14bc-414a-82c4-d1035a11b4a8/how-do-i-updateinsertremove-the-config-file-during-runtime?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260317/change-a-web-config-programmatically-with-c-sharp-net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260317/change-a-web-config-programmatically-with-c-sharp-net)

Comment: This is only for AppSettings section. As in the question, I need to for example add system.identityModel section.