# Changing the Web.config file key value at runtime using C# without changing the structure of the file

Tags: c#, web-config

I have the following code to change key value in `Web.config` file.

```
Configuration webConfigApp = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
webConfigApp.AppSettings.Settings["Email"].Value = "abc@def.com";
webConfigApp.Save();
```

It changes the value successfully but it also affects the file structure. I have some comments in the file that comments are gone after running the above code.

Is there any code which only updates the key value and not affects the entire file?

Comment: check this link also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260317/change-a-web-config-programmatically-with-c-sharp-net

Answer (score 0):

There is an overload on Save method that is

`Save(ConfigurationSaveMode)`

If you set it to `Minimal` it will save only the changed properties.
Please take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationsavemode?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: No, it is still removing comments from a file.

Comment: Are you forced to adding comments into web.config?
Can't you put them in another file?

Comment: I have comments in the Web.config file like:
<!--Email Configuration -->
<add key="Email" value="abc@def.com" />