# Moles and Binding Redirects

Tags: moles, pex-and-moles

The scenario I have is pretty common, one nuget package is using V1.0 and another is using V1.1 so I had to add a Binding Redirect. However, the moles runner appears to be ignoring the binding redirect in both the App.config and assembly config file.

To load the App.config I am using the code found on: [How To Read UnitTest Project's App.Config From Test With HostType("Moles")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105604/how-to-read-unittest-projects-app-config-from-test-with-hosttypemoles)

Any ideas?

Ok took me some time but I have figured out how to mimic the behavior of Binding Redirect. This is the code that I did for that. Leave this as Wiki to allow others to improve upon this code:

```
<!-- language: lang-cs -->
public static void MoleBindingRedirect()
{
    try
    {
        var fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = assembly.Location + ".config";

        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        ConfigurationSection assemblyBindingSection = config.Sections["runtime"];

        var sectionRoot = XDocument.Parse(assemblyBindingSection.SectionInformation.GetRawXml()).Root;
        var assemblyBinding = sectionRoot.Elements(XName.Get("assemblyBinding", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"));
        if (assemblyBinding == null)
            return;        

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var assemblyToLoad = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
            var query = from dependency in assemblyBinding.Elements(XName.Get("dependentAssembly", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"))
                        from identity in dependency.Elements(XName.Get("assemblyIdentity", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"))
                        from attribute in identity.Attributes()
                        where attribute.Value == assemblyToLoad.Name
                        select dependency;

            if (!query.Any())
                return null;

            var assemblyDefinition = query.First();

            var identityElement = assemblyDefinition.Element(XName.Get("assemblyIdentity", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"));
            var bindingRedirectElement = assemblyDefinition.Element(XName.Get("bindingRedirect", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"));

            var assemblyName = identityElement.Attribute("name").Value;
            var assemblyPublicKeyToken = identityElement.Attribute("publicKeyToken");
            var assemblyCulture = identityElement.Attribute("culture");
            var assemblyVersion = bindingRedirectElement.Attribute("newVersion").Value;

            if (assemblyPublicKeyToken != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(assemblyPublicKeyToken.Value))
                assemblyName += ", PublicKeyToken=" + assemblyPublicKeyToken.Value;

            if (assemblyCulture != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(assemblyCulture.Value))
                assemblyName += ", Culture=" + assemblyCulture.Value;

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(assemblyVersion))
                assemblyName += ", Version=" + assemblyVersion;

            return Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
        };
    }
```

Comment: Anyone knows how to apply the lang-cs syntax highlight? It seams to be non working.