# How to specify alternate .config file programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, app-config, configurationsection

I have a custom configuration section, and i'm constructing some unit tests for it. I'd like to be able to specify, somehow, different .config files programatically to test. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what would be different within the different config files.. could you possibly add differect sections to the existing config file..? what do you have so far..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360024/how-do-i-set-a-connection-string-config-programatically-in-net

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/q/4738/706456

Comment: @DJKRAZE -I have a custom configuration collection. I want to test that certain supplied config values throw an exception if they are invalid. However, this test will have the side-effect of breaking my other unit tests. The solution, in my mind, is to have a separate config file where I can supply invalid entries without breaking my other tests

Comment: @oleksii -I think the solution in that question will do the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly your unit tests look like. 
If you have an app.config file in your unit test project where your custom configuration resides, a possible solution would be to open the configuration in a writeable mode and change the config values to your need. After the unit test, restore the old config values.

Use

```
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(...)
```

See also [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms134265.aspx)

If you are looking for a unit testable configuration solutions try out [DslConfig](https://github.com/johannes-brunner/DslConfig)