# how to add new connection string in web.config run time programatically in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I am working on construction ERP.
When user adds new structure i have to create new database for each structure.Whether it is possible using script?

at the same time as i am creating new database for each structure  then it is necessary to create one additional connection string in web.config file

very first i am trying to add new connection string in config file.for that i have written some code.but it gives me error.

```
 string path = Server.MapPath(@"Web.config"); 'or' string path = Server.MapPath("~/Web.config");
        var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(path);
        var section = (ConnectionStringsSection)configuration.GetSection("connectionStrings");
        section.ConnectionStrings.Add(new ConnectionStringSettings(txtStructName.Text, txtStructName.Text, "System.Data.SqlClient"));
        configuration.Save();
```

Error is :The relative virtual path  is not allowed here.

help me to solve this problem.....

Comment: Be aware that the connections strings section is read only. See this for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360024/how-do-i-set-a-connection-string-config-programatically-in-net

Comment: i want to add new connection string.not change in existing string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to specify `web.config`.

Just do

```
WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
```

Comment: i have try for it but "An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to map the path '/'." is the error.....

Comment: @user1838502 is iis configured for that directory to be an application?

Comment: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to map the path '/'.

Comment: @user1838502 make sure you have an application configured in iis.