# Use AspNetSqlMembershipProvider without connectionStrings in Web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, web-config

We use the following services, which are declared in the `Web.config`.

- AspNetSqlMembershipProvider
- AspNetSqlProfileProvider
- AspNetSqlRoleProvider

We are using EntityFramework, and now have a requirement to programmatically set the connection string (it is fetched from the deployment environment, so `Web.config` cannot be used).

The question is, how can we continue to use these Providers, but have a programatic connection string?

We do not want to maintain multiple configs, and we do not want to leave credentials in the `Web.config`.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set a connection string config programatically in .net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360024/how-do-i-set-a-connection-string-config-programatically-in-net)

Comment: Workaround is this!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360024/how-do-i-set-a-connection-string-config-programatically-in-net