# Possibility to add database in sqlCacheDependency collection without web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-string, 3-tier, sqlcachedependency

Situation is like this: I have two projects. One Asp.net and one project which does all data related stuff with database. I keep my connectionstring in a seperate encrypted XML file.
Now instead of requesting all data constantly from sql. I want to use SqlCacheDependency to gain performance. If I follow the instruction they advice me to add a database name in web.config.

```
<caching>
  <sqlCacheDependency enabled ="true">
    <databases>
      <add name="dbName"  connectionStringName="connectionstringName" />
    </databases>
  </sqlCacheDependency>
</caching>
```

Is there any way to this in code. Like in Application Application_Start() event in global.asax file where I can link to a custom method that provides me that connectionstring?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to David Gardiner's work around.
I found in the following post.

[How do I set a connection string config programatically in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360024/how-do-i-set-a-connection-string-config-programatically-in-net)

I've put it in the Global.asax application load event. Now I can from my sqlcachedependency section in web.config. to that existing connectionStringName from the connectionstring collection.