# C# Change dataConfiguration defaultDatabase programmatically

Tags: c#, enterprise-library, web-config

I have the following code in which I want to change the default database in code behind.

**Web.config**

```
<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="olddatabasename"/>
```

**My code behind**

```
DatabaseSettings dbSettings = (DatabaseSettings)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("dataConfiguration");
dbSettings.DefaultDatabase = "newdatabasename";
```

But it gives the following error:

**The configuration is read only**

How can I change this in code behind?

Comment: You're probably better off storing that in a *separate* configuration mechanism that you can control better.

Comment: You might want to store the database and connection string in the registry: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649224.aspx

Comment: I'd just as soon get flogged than to store anything in the registry.  Perhaps your own XML file?

Comment: So is there no way of achieving this, without the suggestions?

Comment: Why does it have to be that particular configuration entry?

Comment: I have a drodpwn which allows the user to select database from it...so  I want to change this based on the selection

Comment: Yes, but you can store the value of that dropdown anywhere.

Comment: Yes, but the dropdown has the list of databases.When the user selects the list of database name I want to change this dafault database so all calls to database are made to the selected database.

Comment: this may be what you are looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260317/change-a-web-config-programmatically-with-c-sharp-net

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360024/how-do-i-set-a-connection-string-config-programatically-in-net

Answer (score 0):

Using the link by @Audor from comments I was able to fix the issue:

```
var settings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("dataConfiguration");
var fi = typeof(ConfigurationElement).GetField("_bReadOnly", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
fi.SetValue(settings, false);
DatabaseSettings dbSettings = (DatabaseSettings)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("dataConfiguration");
dbSettings.DefaultDatabase = databseName;
```